# ElasticSearch NEST QueryParsingException bool query does not support filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST 2.3.2 to query ElasticSearch and need to create a conditional filter for FollowUpDateTime field based on optional boolean. If that boolean

- is true - want to see all records with non-blank date,
- is false - records without date,
- is null - show all records.

Here's what I have in Nest:

```
                    var containers = new QueryContainer[7];
                    //Size is based on hte number of search parameters.. 
                    var descriptor = new QueryContainerDescriptor<EsNoteModel>();

                    var filters = new QueryContainer[1];
                    var filterdescriptor = new QueryContainerDescriptor<EsNoteModel>();  

       /*...... some code for other parameters here .....*/

        if (hasFollowUpDate.HasValue)
                    {
                        if ((bool) hasFollowUpDate)
                        {
                            //If true shows only with a non-blank follow-up date
                            filters[0] = filterdescriptor.Exists(ff => ff.Field("FollowUpDateTime"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //If false shows only notes with a blank follow-up date
                            filters[0] = filterdescriptor.Missing(ff => ff.Field("FollowUpDateTime"));
                        }
                    }

/*...... CALL to ES below .....*/    

                    var result = ElasticSearchClient.Search<EsNoteModel>(body => body
                        .From(offset - 1)
                        .Size(rows)
                        .Query(q => q
                            .Bool(b => b
                                  .Must(containers)
                                  .Filter(f => f.Bool(t => t.Must(filters)))
                                  )
                                )

                        .Sort(s => s
                            .Field(f => f
                                .Field(p => p.NoteDate)
                                .Order(SortOrder.Descending)))

                        );
```

The problem is that the query above generated the error. Please see below:

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on
>   POST: /_search?pretty=true
>
> ## Audit trail of this API call:
>
> - BadResponse: Node: http://**********.es.amazonaws.com/ Took: 00:00:00.1381301
>
>   ## OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    at
>
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData
>   requestData)

```
# Request:
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 25,
  "sort": [
    {
      "NoteDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "CustomerId": {
              "query": "2810855"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "FollowUpDateTime"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response below:

```
# Response:
{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[-t7SwBo_TjeH_98h_56ANw][customernote][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Neophyte][inet[/x.x.x.x:y]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[customernote][0]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@2d55231>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"28_10855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"bool\": {\r\n            \"must\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"exists\": {\r\n                  \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n            ]\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[TOOugCq3ROqF9CGnHIay2g][customernote][1]: SearchParseException[[customernote][1]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@562f97b5>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"28_10855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"bool\": {\r\n            \"must\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"exists\": {\r\n                  \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n            ]\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[TOOugCq3ROqF9CGnHIay2g][customernote][2]: SearchParseException[[customernote][2]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@394cf46e>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"28_10855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"bool\": {\r\n            \"must\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"exists\": {\r\n                  \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n            ]\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[-t7SwBo_TjeH_98h_56ANw][customernote][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Neophyte][inet[/x.x.x.x:y]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[customernote][3]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@46d07ba8>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"28_10855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"bool\": {\r\n            \"must\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"exists\": {\r\n                  \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n            ]\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[TOOugCq3ROqF9CGnHIay2g][customernote][4]: SearchParseException[[customernote][4]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@74fb3710>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"28_10855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"bool\": {\r\n            \"must\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"exists\": {\r\n                  \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n            ]\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

As you see error reports "nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]];" Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in this example? Is this a proper use of filter clause?

**** UPDATE

changed query

```
 var result = ElasticSearchClient.Search<EsNoteModel>(body => body
                .From(offset - 1)
                .Size(rows)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                          .Must(containers)
                          .Filter(filters)
                          )
                        )

                .Sort(s => s
                    .Field(f => f
                        .Field(p => p.NoteDate)
                        .Order(SortOrder.Descending)))

                );
```

request to

```
# Request:
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 25,
  "sort": [
    {
      "NoteDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "CustomerId": {
              "query": "2810855"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "FollowUpDateTime"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

getting response error:

```
# Response:
{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[TOOugCq3ROqF9CGnHIay2g][customernote][0]: SearchParseException[[customernote][0]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@4839a60c>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"2810855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"exists\": {\r\n            \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[-t7SwBo_TjeH_98h_56ANw][customernote][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Neophyte][inet[/x.x.x.x:y]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[customernote][1]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@21d845ae>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"2810855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"exists\": {\r\n            \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[-t7SwBo_TjeH_98h_56ANw][customernote][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Neophyte][inet[/x.x.x.x:y]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[customernote][2]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@6124d214>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"2810855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"exists\": {\r\n            \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[TOOugCq3ROqF9CGnHIay2g][customernote][3]: SearchParseException[[customernote][3]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@f884425>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"2810855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"exists\": {\r\n            \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }{[-t7SwBo_TjeH_98h_56ANw][customernote][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Neophyte][inet[/x.x.x.x:y]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[customernote][4]: from[0],size[25],sort[<custom:\"NoteDate\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@77228f64>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\r\n  \"from\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 25,\r\n  \"sort\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"NoteDate\": {\r\n        \"order\": \"desc\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"query\": {\r\n    \"bool\": {\r\n      \"must\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"match\": {\r\n            \"CustomerId\": {\r\n              \"query\": \"2810855\"\r\n            }\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"filter\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"exists\": {\r\n            \"field\": \"FollowUpDateTime\"\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

Basically same error

nested: QueryParsingException[[customernote] bool query does not support [filter]];

Comment: Bool queries can only have a filter from elasticsearch 2 onwards.

Comment: using Elasticsearch.Net.2.3.2

Comment: That's the client you're using but the server is 1.5.2 (since that is the only version provided by the aws elasticsearch service, which you appear to be using)

Comment: Frederick - you deserve a star! thank you

Comment: The major versions of NEST are compatible with the major versions of Elasticsearch so for Elasticsearch 1.5.2, you should use the latest NEST 1.x, which at this time is 1.8.2. Check out the compatibility matrix on github - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Answer (score 1):

Apparently we have in out .NET 4.0 project the following references to

1. Elasticsearch.Net - official low level elasticsearch client
   packages\Elasticsearch.Net.2.3.2\lib\net45\Elasticsearch.Net.dll
2. NEST - official high level elasticsearch client
   packages\NEST.2.3.2\lib\net45\Nest.dll

interesting fact they still use deprecated queries. as mentioned by Frederick here

> the client you're using but the server is 1.5.2 (since that is the
>   only version provided by the aws elasticsearch service, which you
>   appear to be using)

see below - it works:

```
            var query = new QueryContainer[8];//Size is based on hte number of search parameters
            var descriptor = new QueryContainerDescriptor<EsNoteModel>();

/*........... skipping here some code for other parameters ..........*/

 if (hasFollowUpDate.HasValue)
            {
                if ((bool) hasFollowUpDate)
                {
                    //If true shows only with a non-blank follow-up date
                    query[7] = descriptor.Filtered(p => p.Filter(f => f.Exists(r => r.Field(u => u.FollowUpDateTime))));
                }
                else
                {
                    ////If false shows only notes with a blank follow-up date
                    query[7] = descriptor.Filtered(p => p.Filter(f => f.Missing(r => r.Field(u => u.FollowUpDateTime))));
                }
            }

            var result = ElasticSearchClient.Search<EsNoteModel>(body => body
                .From(offset - 1)
                .Size(rows)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                          .Must(query)
                          )
                        )

                .Sort(s => s
                    .Field(f => f
                        .Field(p => p.NoteDate)
                        .Order(SortOrder.Descending)))

                );
```

So simply replacing word BOOL to Filtered - did the trick

Comment: how did you connect aws ES using nest? Simple post doesnt work I thinkt. It requires some security to be added

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically using a `QueryContainer` or `FilterContainer`.  Here is a very similar one from our solution:

```
var query = new List<QueryContainer>
{
    Query<AlertForReporting>.Range(r => r.OnField(f => f.AlertDate)
                                          .Greater(start.ToEPCISFormat())
                                          .Lower(end.ToEPCISFormat())
        )
};


var result = ElasticClient.Search<AlertForReporting>(s =>
                        s.Size(0)
                            .Query(q =>
                                q.Bool(b =>
                                        b.Must(query.ToArray())
                                    )
                            ));
```

Comment: we already using QueryContainer for some other parameters for DateRange, Match and QueryStrings searches. (code updated above). do we need to have use both: FilterContainer and QueryContainer? and if so - how? I am searching for answer.. reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#breaking_20_query_dsl_changes

Comment: @NataliaZolotareva In NEST 1.x, there is `FilterContainer` and `QueryContainer`, the former is used where a filter is expected and the latter, where a query is expected. In NEST 2.x which works with Elasticsearch 2.x, there is only QueryContainer to reflect the change in Elasticsearch where filters and queries merged. In NEST 2.x, you use `QueryContainer` where you would have used `QueryContainer` and `FilterContainer` in NEST 1.x